# After Windows 10 update, VMware doesn't detect network adapter

Tags: windows, windows-10, vmware

After an automatic Windows 10 update, my VMware Ubuntu lost its Internet connection. I looked in settings and found out the network adapter Marvell Yukon adapter was missing. I looked up some solutions online and they did not work. How can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Windows 10 is nasty.  I had the same problem after installing the 'Anniversary Update' and ended up fixing it by reinstalling the VMware package in 'Repair' mode, as referenced on related question: [VMware Workstation not installing network adapters on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/948408/vmware-workstation-not-installing-network-adapters-on-windows-10)
- of course, you need to have the VMware installation package available (or you can download the latest from their website: https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/downloads).

To reinstall in 'Repair' mode, simply:

1. Find where you saved and run the VMware installation package.
2. Choose 'Repair' and proceed.

**Note**: a select few reported that they had to uninstall their existing VMware network adapters first.  You may want to do that up front if you're familiar, since it's quick and easy... the basic steps:

1. Open Control Panel: Windows Key + Pause/Break
2. Open Device Manager (left side)
3. Under the 'Network adapters' section, right-click and Uninstall all 'VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapters'.

No restart was necessary on my end.  Alas, I had internet access within the virtual machine, once again!

Good luck!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 3):

I found an easier way to fix the problem.

Under the Edit menu select "Virtual Network Editor". You'll probably see that no networks are listed, but it doesn't matter. Now click "Restore Default" (at bottom left in VS 8). It will uninstall and reinstall all virtual network adapters. If you had custom settings then you'll have to re-do once it finishes.

I'm using VS 8.06 under Win 10 Anniversary Edition.

Answer (score -1):

I reinstalled and it fixed the problem.

Comment: Can you please tell us exactly what you reinstalled? Windows 10? VMWare? Network drivers? Something else? As it stands this answer is useless.